# Why is my react web app msal login is not working in the new teams version?

Tags: reactjs, iframe, microsoft-teams, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-teams-js

I am a web developer. The website I am working on is embed as an iframe in teams. In the older version of teams, the use clicks on login and it proceeds to the login page (not a popup login).

In the new version, when I click login, msal login does not work.

I tried to use login direct instead of login popup when embedded as iframe.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Kindly share more information about your issue along with the error logs.